# How to change the secondary IP address to primary IP address

Tags: c, network-programming

I am developing a network application, in C, that needs to be run on a linux PC. The machine has one NIC that has been assigned three IP addresses(one Primary and two secondary ip address).

In a specific scenario, I need to change one of the secondary IP addresses to primary IP address. Is there any possible method for achieving this functionality in C?

This is required since primary IP address is used as the source IP address in an outgoing IP packet. I need to use the secondary IP address as the source address in outgoing packets in some particular conditions.

Comment: _"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."_

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Use `system()` to invoke `ifconfig` to do the change. That's the simplest approach.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks for the reply. I know how to do it from terminal and its possible to run those commands using system API. But I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: @sreeyesh Why is that not a good solution? Perhaps I didn't understand your problem, but `ifconfig` is a fairly nice and portable abstraction over the hairy system API Linux has to configure its network stack.

Comment: @FUZxxl Correct me if I am wrong. I have heard that system API is inefficient as it involves forking another process to execute a shell command.

Comment: @sreeyesh Yes it does. Is that a problem? How often per second are you trying to change the system's IP address? 100 times? 1000 times? A fork & exec takes about 10ms on my system. Is this really too slow for your purpose?

Comment: @FUZxxl  You are right! But I am developing application for a network device with low performance hardware. So the code should be as efficient as possible. That's why I'm trying for an alternative. If there isn't any I'll stick to the 'system()' method.

Comment: @sreeyesh You can directly interact with the Linux kernel, run `strace` on `ifconfig` to see how. That said, that's going to be much more complex and error prone than invoking `ifconfig` while being only slightly faster.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks! I will definitely try that :)

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking without rebinding all of the addresses.  However, from the network perspective, there really isn't a difference between the addresses.  You can certainly specify that you'd like to bind to a specific address when creating a listener, but you cannot do this when specifying the responding address because the IP stack at that point already has an IP address as an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of these IP addresses to be your source address after `socket()` and before `connect()` call via `bind()` call.
Look at instructions in [man bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) or [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#bind).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought of this solution first but dropped, as there are lots of already deployed network applications running on the device and I am not allowed to make changes in them.